# Swagger sending null value

Tags: c#, get, filtering

I'm trying to do apply a Filter into my method, but having trouble when trying to send the parameter with swagger...

This is my method

```
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("anyRoute")]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(List<ViewModel>), (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
        [ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.NoContent)]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetMehod([FromQuery] Filter filter)
        {
            var result = await _service.GetApproved(filter);

            if (result.Count() == 0)
                return NoContent();

            return Ok(result);
       }
```

This is my filter

```
public class Filter
    {
        public string Filter { get; set; }
    }
```

When I try to debug, my parameter is null, and my filter doesn't work

Comment: I think you need to provide some more information. What does your request look like?

Comment: Please add your query as well. Seems like it just can't parse it.

Comment: When you ask for my request, you mean this `http://localhost:5564/api/v1/TimeEntries/toBill?Filter=MockedName`

Comment: @NeedHelpASAP I`m using Entity Framework, but when my Filter goes to my service he's already null

Comment: @RavelSbrissaOkada So, you are trying to map a string ("MockedName") to an object? Try changing your method signature to take a string parameter instead (e.g. GetMethod([FromQuery]string filter).

Comment: @kaffekopp In this way worked! But can you tell me why the first way doesn't work?

Comment: @RavelSbrissaOkada The parameter you pass in your request "MockedName" is just a string. There is now way for the framework to understand by your request/code that you actually mean it to be mapped to a certain property of a class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that your Filter parameter has the same name of one of it's properties. And when you make a request like this: `http://localhost:5564/api/v1/TimeEntries/toBill?Filter=MockedName` ASP.Net does not know if you want to bind it to the parameter filter or the property of the parameter filter.

I made a PoC and the builder gives me this warning:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>
> Warning   MVC1004 Property on type 'FilterClass' has the same name as
>   parameter 'filter'. This may result in incorrect model binding.
>   Consider renaming the parameter or using a model binding attribute to
>   override the
>   name.

You have 3 options to solve it:

**1) Change the name of your parameter and make the exact same request:**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetMehod([FromQuery] Filter anyName)
{
    var result = await _service.GetApproved(anyName.Filter);

    if (result.Count() == 0)
        return NoContent();

        return Ok(result);
}
```

Request Url: `http://localhost:5564/api/v1/TimeEntries/toBill?filter=MockedName`

**2) Keep your C# code as it is now and change querystring name on your request, adding parameterName.PropertyName=value.**

Request Url: `http://localhost:5564/api/v1/TimeEntries/toBill?filter.Filter=MockedName`

**3) As you only need this string I suggest you to change the parameter type of your action.**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetMehod([FromQuery] string filter)
{
    var result = await _service.GetApproved(filter);

    if (result.Count() == 0)
        return NoContent();

        return Ok(result);
}
```

If your Filter class has only one property I suggest you to use option 3; Else option 1 will be better.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: Sorry. How can you do what?

Comment: Change my request to specify the property of my object

Comment: Using parameter name and property name on query string. In your case your query string should be filter.Filter Like this: http://localhost:5564/api/v1/TimeEntries/toBill?filter.Filter=MockedName

Comment: I edited the answer to give you more detailed explanation.

Comment: If it solve your question I apreciatte if you could mark the answer as correct. It will help other users with the same problem in the future too.

Comment: Oh, sorry, it resolved my problem, but my real problem was my parameter and property has the same name, I changed and works.
Like your first solution
Thank you all